# How to sort linked list by date?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, sorting

We're suppose to make a scheduler with a title, some details, a date and a classified priority using a sorted linked lists.

I managed to sort them by priority but first I have to sort them by date.
Since the date I am using is a structure with an int month, int day, int year. I have trouble sorting all 3 at the same time. I can only figure out how to sort either per year or per day or per month.

Here's my dummy code for sorting dates:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct D{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
}DATE;

typedef struct node_tag{
    DATE d;
    struct node_tag * next;
}NODE;

int main(){
    NODE *head = NULL;
    NODE *temp, *ptr, *print;
    int usr = 1;
    while(usr!=0){
    DATE date;
    scanf("%d", &usr);
    printf("Enter date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &date.month, &date.day, &date.year);
    temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp->d.month = date.month;
    temp->d.day = date.day;
    temp->d.year = date.year;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL || head->d.year > temp->d.year){
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else if(head == NULL || head->d.year == temp->d.year){
        if(head->d.month > temp->d.month){
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }

    }
    else{
        ptr = head;
        while(ptr->next !=NULL && ptr->next->d.year < temp->d.year){
            ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    temp->next = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = temp;
}
    }
    print = head;
    while(print!= NULL){ //prints the list
            printf("%d %d %d\n", print->d.month, print->d.day, print->d.year);
            print = print->next;
        }
}
```

Can I get any tips and help?

Comment: Well, you can coalesce the three pieces of data into one integer, say `10000*y + 100*m + d`. Or you could write a comparison function that compares the year, month and day of two dates separately.

Comment: @Oehm, gasp! Deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
// On the lines of M oehm's 2nd approach
// Given the way you store the time, this should work 
int date_compare(DATE *t1, DATE *t2) {
    // returns 1 if t1 greater than t2, -1 if t1 < t2, 0 if equal
    if (t1->year > t2->year) return(1);
    if (t1->year < t2->year) return(-1);
    // year matches. so check month
    if (t1->month > t2->month) return(1);
    if (t1->month < t2->month) return(-1);
    // month aslo matches. so check day
    if (t1->day > t2->day) return(1);
    if (t1->day < t2->day) return(-1);
    // day also matches
    return(0);
}
```